# Why i can not run the bcp in my sql server?

Tags: sql-server

I'm beginner in sql server and want to save my select query result to text file,write this:

```
exec xp_cmdshell 'bcp "SELECT [id]
      ,[name]
  FROM [dbo].[myTABLE]" queryout f:\myOut.txt '
```

but i get this error:
[image]

how can i solve that?

Comment: Did my answer provide any insights into the problem you are facing?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the database you are querying in the query. Try the following query in your BCP statement instead:

```
SELECT [id]
      ,[name]
FROM [myDatabase].[dbo].[myTABLE]
```

where `myDatabase` is the name of the database you are querying.

Alternatively you can pass the database name to your BCP command using the `-d [myDatabase]`.